# What other languages have features and/or libraries similar to Perl's format?

Tags: ruby, perl, format

I may be in the minority here, but I very much enjoy [Perl's formats](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlform).  I especially like being able to wrap a long piece of text within a column ("~~  ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" type stuff).  Are there any other programming languages that have similar features, or libraries that implement similar features?  I am especially interested in any libraries that implement something similar for Ruby, but I'm also curious about any other options.

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[FormatR](http://formatr.rubyforge.org/) provides Perl-like formats for Ruby.

Here is an example from the documentation:

```
require "formatr"
include FormatR

top_ex = <<DOT
   Piggy Locations for @<< @#, @###
                     month, day, year

Number: location              toe size
-------------------------------------------
DOT

ex = <<TOD
@)      @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<       @#.##
num,    location,             toe_size
TOD

body_fmt = Format.new (top_ex, ex)

body_fmt.setPageLength(10)
num = 1

month = "Sep"
day = 18
year = 2001
["Market", "Home", "Eating Roast Beef", "Having None", "On the way home"].each {|location|
    toe_size = (num * 3.5)
    body_fmt.printFormat(binding)
    num += 1
}
```

Which produces:

```
   Piggy Locations for Sep 18, 2001

Number: location              toe size
-------------------------------------------
1)      Market                   3.50
2)      Home                     7.00
3)      Eating Roast Beef       10.50
4)      Having None             14.00
5)      On the way home         17.50
```

Answer (score 13):

I seem to recall something similar in Fortran when I used it many years ago (however, it may well have have been a third-party library).

As for other options in Perl, have a look at [`Perl6::Form`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Perl6::Form).

The `form` function replaces [`format`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/format.html) in Perl6. Damian Conway in "[Perl Best Practices](http://google.com/search?btnI=&q=%22Perl+Best+Practices%22)" recommends using [`Perl6::Form`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Perl6::Form) with Perl5 citing the following issues with [`format`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html)....

- statically defined
- rely on global variables for configuration and pkg variables for data they format on
- uses named filehandles (only)
- not recursive or re-entrant

Here is a [`Perl6::Form`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Perl6::Form) variation on the Ruby example by Robert Gamble....

```
use Perl6::Form;

my ( $month, $day, $year ) = qw'Sep 18 2001';
my ( $num, $numb, $location, $toe_size );

for ( "Market", "Home", "Eating Roast Beef", "Having None", "On the way home" ) {
    push @$numb,     ++$num;
    push @$location, $_;
    push @$toe_size, $num * 3.5;
}

print form
    '   Piggy Locations for {>>>}{>>}, {<<<<}',
                          $month, $day, $year ,
    "",
    '  Number: location              toe size',
    '  --------------------------------------',
    '{]})      {[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[}       {].0} ',
     $numb,    $location,              $toe_size;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is the [Lisp `(format ...)` function](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html). It supports looping, conditionals, and a whole bunch of other fun stuff.

for example (copied from above link):

```
(defparameter *english-list*
  "~{~#[~;~a~;~a and ~a~:;~@{~a~#[~;, and ~:;, ~]~}~]~}")

(format nil *english-list* '())       ;' ==> ""
(format nil *english-list* '(1))      ;' ==> "1"
(format nil *english-list* '(1 2))    ;' ==> "1 and 2"
(format nil *english-list* '(1 2 3))  ;' ==> "1, 2, and 3"
(format nil *english-list* '(1 2 3 4));' ==> "1, 2, 3, and 4"
```