# How do I write text in aligned columns in Perl?

Tags: perl, format

I am trying to write to a file from Perl. I just want to write the data in a tab-delimited format. However, the data that I am writing has varying lengths and is not lining up.

For example, I am trying to write something like this:

```
Name  Education   Fav_Car  MoneyInBank
josh  High School Porche   500
SomeOtherName  PHD  Hyundai   50000
```

I just want the data to be lined up with the headers that I have on the top.

I am outputting the data like so:

```
 printf FILE ("%s%20s%20s\n", "Name", "Ed", "Car");
 while (($name, $ed, $car) = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
     printf FILE ("%s>>>>>>>>>>>>>%40s%40s\n", $name, $ed, $car);
 };
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Tab-delimited data (where the fields are not consistent in length) does not line up when opened in a text editor.

Solutions:

- Open the file in a spreadsheet.
- Open it in a word processor, select all the text, and define appropriate tab stops. (thanks, [Justsalt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13693/justsalt))
- In your text editor, set your tab width to a value larger than any of your fields.
- Use spaces instead of tabs (e.g., [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) with field widths, or [formats](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html)).

For example, you might use

```
printf("%-15s %-15s %-10s %9s\n", $name, $edu, $car, $cash);
```

The `-` after the `%` causes the field to be left justified.  Numbers (like money) are usually right-justified (which is the default).

Comment: Or open it in a word processor and define appropriate tab stops.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the Perl [format](http://www.webreference.com/programming/perl/format/) command.

Comment: I wouldn't use format for any new projects, use Perl6::Form instead.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Perl6::Form](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl6-Form/) CPAN module.

The previous question/answer *[What Other Languages Have Features And Or Libraries Similar To Perls Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236629/what-other-languages-have-features-and-or-libraries-similar-to-perls-format/237031#237031)* on Stack Overflow may help.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the way like C's printf, you can adjust the width dynamically with "*",

```
printf FILE ("%*s%*s%*s\n", 20, "Name", length($blah), "Ed", 20, "Car");
```

Answer (score 1):

The [printf](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#printf-FILEHANDLE-FORMAT%2C-LIST) function does this as in C.  For 20 character fields:

```
printf("%20s%20s%20s$20S\n", $name, $ed, $car, $money);
```

Comment: Do those need to be %-20 to left justify?

Comment: how can i make them left justified?

Comment: @styris: See Daniel L's comment on this very question!

Comment: What does `$20S` mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you're working on Linux, an easy solution would be to use the [column](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_column.htm) system command, with the `-t` flag. Just print the space-separated table to a file, and just use the column command on that file.

```
system("column -t file > new_file");
```