# How can I use Unicode characters when I write to Perl's format?

Tags: perl, email, unicode, format

Basically I have a database where I get `$lastname`, `$firstname`, `$rid`, `$since`, `$times` and `$ip` from.

Using a Perl script, I format the data to send it via e-mail. Since the `$lastname` and `$firstname` can contain special chars (for instance ä, ü, ß, é,...) I first decode the strings.

```
my $fullname = decode("utf8", $lastname) . ', ' . decode("utf8", $firstname);
my $send = swrite(<<'END', $ip, $fullname, $rid, $since, $times);
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @<<<<<<<<<< @<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @>>END
```

Without `decode`, the special chars are garbage (ä becomes Ã€) and the rest is OK.
With `decode`, everything is fine except the lines with name containing special chars have a couple of `<` too many.

Why is that? And how do I remove them?

Edit: `swrite` is from [`perldoc perlform`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html#Accessing-Formatting-Internals)

```
sub swrite {
  my $format = shift;
  $^A = '';
  formline($format, @_);
  return $^A;
}
```

Edit2: 
The problem is not the terminal nor STDOUT. I use:

```
use Mail::Sender;
use vars qw($sender);
#...
$sender->MailMsg({to => $mailto, 
  cc=> "", 
  bcc => "", 
  subject => "subject", 
  msg => $send});
```

And the characters are badly shown when receiving the email.

Edit 3:
The data I get is already scrambled. I get 'Ã€' instead of 'ä' and that's why my format fails, because the number of chars decreases when using decode.

Comment: Perl does not provide an `swrite` function.  Are you using the one from `perldoc perlform` or is it something else?  Without that information any help will just be guesses.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the code from swrite.

Comment: what terminal/OS are you using? That may be affecting things.

Comment: It looks like your problem is that the email client can't handle UTF-8 plaintext.  You may need to write the email message as MIME Multipart and specify the text type as UTF-8.

Comment: @Paul: I use a xen virtual machine (2.6.18-6-xen-amd64) running on a Debian "Lenny". The DB is PostgresSQL version 7.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never had the desire to learn about formats. This is a bad answer because I am unable to offer any insight into your problem and/or potential solutions, but others have already done that. I am going to offer two suggestions for replacements.

The first one, [`Perl6::Form`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Perl6::Form) ought to be useful as a *better* `format` although I had never used it until I put together this example today. On the other hand, I have used [`Text::Table`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::Table) and it is very useful for creating tables in plain text (most of the time, I just generate HTML, but email is still one of those places where plain text is plainly better).

#### [`Perl6::Form`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Perl6::Form) example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Perl6::Form;

my @data = (
    ['127.0.0.1', 'Johnny Smithey', 'JLNSJIV', 14, 5],
    ['127.0.0.2', 'Ömer Seyfettin Şınas', 'OSS3', 25, 5],
);

for my $data_ref ( @data ) {
    print format_data($data_ref);
}

sub format_data {
    my ($data) = @_;
    return form
        '{<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<} {<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<} ' .
        '{<<<<<<<<<<} {<<<<<<<<<<<<<<} {>>}',
        @$data;
}
```

#### [`Text::Table`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::Table) example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Table;

my %common_options = (
    align => 'left',
    title_align => 'center',
);

my $sep = \' ';

my $table = Text::Table->new(
    {
        title  => 'IP Address',
        sample => '<' x 15,
        %common_options,
    },
    $sep,
    {
        title => 'Full Name',
        sample => '<' x 34,
        %common_options,
    },
    $sep,
    {
        title => 'RID',
        sample => '<' x 10,
        %common_options,
    },
    $sep,
    {
        title => 'Since',
        sample => '<' x 14,
        %common_options,
    },
    $sep,
    {
        title => 'Times',
        sample => '>' x 2,
        align => 'right',
        title_align => 'center'
    },
);

$table->rule('');

$table->load(
['127.0.0.1', 'Johnny Smith-Jones', 'JLNSJIV', '20090814010203', 5],
['127.0.0.2', 'Ömer Seyfettin Şınas', 'OSS3', '20071211101112', 3],
['192.168.172.144', 'Jane Doe', 'JD156', '20080101010101', 1],
);

print $table->table;
```

Comment: +1  For bit more about Perl6::Form also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236629/what-other-languages-have-features-and-or-libraries-similar-to-perls-format/237031#237031

Answer (score 4):

The problem there is that the `format` engine isn't understanding your UTF-8; it thinks each byte is a character.  I don't actually know if you can get `formline` (the underlying mechanism of `swrite`) to speak Unicode, but try this:

```
use open qw( :std :encoding(UTF-8) );
```

This attempts to apply UTF-8 encoding as broadly as possible.

You will probably need to skip your `decode` usage with this on.

Comment: I get a "Too late for "-CSD" option at ./test.pl line 1."
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Researching it a bit, it looks like at some point using `-C` on the shebang line became unsupported.  Edited to provide what I hope is a substitute.

Answer (score 4):

My minimal test case seems to think that format handles Unicode just fine:

```
perl -MEncode -e 'formline("X@<<X", Encode::decode("utf-8","ほげぼげ")); print $^A'
```

The output is three characters, as expected.  But anyway, `format` is seriously deprecated.  Time to use something else instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the `swrite` function from `perldoc perlform`, your problem is either that `STDOUT` is not setup for UTF-8 or your terminal cannot handle UTF-8.  For the first case, you have a few options.  The first is to use binmode to tell `STDOUT` to expect UTF-8:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Carp;

sub swrite {
    croak "usage: swrite PICTURE ARGS" unless @_;
    my $format = shift;
    $^A = "";
    formline($format, @_);
    return $^A;
}

my $fmt = "@<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @<<<<<<<<<< @<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @>>";

binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

my ($ip, $rid, $since, $times) = qw/1.1.1.1 5 2009-08-19 20/;
my $firstname = "Ch\x{e4}s";
my $lastname  = "\x{d6}wens";
my $fullname  = "$lastname, $firstname";
my $send      = swrite $fmt, $ip, $fullname, $rid, $since, $times;
print "$send\n";
```

Another option is set the PERL_UNICODE environment variable to SDL (this is similar to chaos's -CSD on the commandline):

```
PERL_UNICODE=SDL perl script.pl
```

or

```
export PERL_UNICODE=SDL
perl script.pl
```

There are other ways of telling `STDOUT` to expect UTF-8, but I can't remember them off the top of my head (I put `export PERL_UNICODE=SDL` in my `.profile` a long time ago).

If the problem is your terminal, well you need to either configure it properly or get a different terminal.  The code above works on a properly configured terminal, so you can use it as a test.

Comment: Actually I'm not using the terminal nor STDOUT.  See my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about formats or swrite, but I do know about your email problem.

The characters you see in the received email are UTF-8. However, your mailer is set to display something else by default (like Windows-1252 or Latin-1).

The solution is to add a header in your email which informs the mail program about the character encoding, so that it can display it correctly. The headers you need to add to the email are:

```
Mime-version: 1.0
Content-type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
```

(or another charset, making sure that it correspond's to the body of the email)

Additionally, you may want to encode the email into a 7bit encoding like "quoted-printable", and add the corresponding header:

```
Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable
```

That last encoding can be done with the MIME::QuotedPrint module.