# How to "pad" a variable-length string to have an aligned last column

Tags: perl

I have an input of the following format:

---

```
09:08:11        XXXXXXXXXXXXX  1.1.1.1          
09:09:03        YYYYYYYY  2.2.2.2         
09:12:37        ZZZZ   3.3.3.3
```

---

I am able to extract these individuals fields easily using the regex `/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+/`. I named them `$time`, `$name`, and `$number`. My problem is I want to display this so that the `$number` aligns perfectly. Because the `$name` can be of any length, what is the best solution for this?

I would like for the output to look like this. Please note that I had to use dots to align the last field since I wasn't able use the spacebar to do this, not sure why. Anyhoo.

---

```
09:08:11        XXXXXXXXXXXXX    1.1.1.1          
09:09:03        YYYYYYYY         2.2.2.2         
09:12:37        ZZZZ             3.3.3.3
```

---

I thought about putting the `$name` into an array. And then use a function to find the one with the longest character count. Finally I would pad out the shorter name to match the longest name. Is there a better and more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Use the Code formatting option to specify that fixed-width font and preformatting should be used. :)

Comment: I was just making this edit on my phone, until I realized it was too difficult.

Comment: Are the numbers always one digit each? If not, what do you want to do?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Good to know I can add the spaces in the code option.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For formatting, try using the [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) function, as in

```
$line = sprintf "%-12s %-20s %-s\n", $time, $name, $number;
```

(the minus sign means left-justify)

Answer (score 5):

It was given by someone [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/addings-columns-in-perl-script-667040/):

```
my($name, $telephone, $stime);

format Infos =
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$name,             $telephone,         $stime
.

$~ = 'Infos';

($name, $telephone, $stime) = ('Name:', 'Telephone:', 'Start Time:');
write;

($name, $telephone, $stime) = ('Mike Bax', 'tel-41596', 'Fri 8/22 13:31');
write;
```

You can change variables names, and it should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Perl6::Form](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl6-Form/).

This is the recommended approach over using [format](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html). See this previous Stack Overflow answer: *[What other languages have features and/or libraries similar to Perl's format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236629/what-other-languages-have-features-and-or-libraries-similar-to-perls-format/237031#237031)*

Here is an example of Perl6::Form doing just what you want with your data:

```
use Perl6::Form;

my ($time, $name, $number);

my @data = (
    [ qw(09:08:11 XXXXXXXXXXXXX 1.1.1.1) ],
    [ qw(09:09:03 YYYYYYYY 2.2.2.2)      ],
    [ qw(09:12:37 ZZZZ 3.3.3.3)          ],
);

for my $line (@data) {
    push @$time,   $line->[0];
    push @$name,   $line->[1];
    push @$number, $line->[2];
}

print form
    '{[[[[[[}    {[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[}    {[[[[[[}',
    $time,       $name,                    $number;
```

NB. If your data fields ever become larger than the form fields specified then you will run into formatting issues (and same thing also applies to sprintf and format solutions).

It's easy to fix depending on what your output requirements are. For example, if you want to maintain tabular stability then...

```
print form { layout => 'tabular' },
    '{[[[[[[}    {[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[}    {[[[[[[}',
    $time,       $name,                    $number;
```

...will word wrap each column for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not know the maximum width of the middle field, you will have to make two passes over the data as [@ijw notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512253/how-to-pad-a-variable-length-string-to-have-an-aligned-last-column/1513550#1513550).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Fcntl qw( :seek );

my $max_length = 0;
my $data_pos = tell DATA;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    last unless $line =~ /\S/;
    my $name = (split ' ', $line)[1];
    my $name_length = length $name;
    $max_length = $name_length if $name_length > $max_length;
}

seek DATA, $data_pos, SEEK_SET;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    last unless $line =~ /\S/;
    my ($date, $name, $ip) = split ' ', $line;
    printf "%s %-${max_length}s %s\n", $date, $name, $ip;
}

__DATA__
09:08:11        XXXXXXXXXXXXX  1.1.1.1
09:09:03        YYYYYYYY  2.2.2.2
09:12:37        ZZZZ   3.3.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, you're going to have to do with two passes - one to find the length, one to print, using that length in the formatting.  I would go with the sprintf answer already given for the formatting, personally, just varying the number in it.

Exactly how you do the two passes rather depends on where the data is coming from - reading a file twice might be wiser than preprocessing it into memory if the file is huge, but the array solution you're proposing sounds good to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
      $lineLength = length($line1);
      write;
}
close FD1;

format STDOUT =
@>>>>> @*
$lineLength,$line1
.
;
```

So, in above example, "$lineLength" is pushed to the right with leading spaces.